# como crear un arreglo de arreglos?

Tags: javascript

Intento que mis datos que son devuelto como un array de objetos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se conviertan a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es posible? alguna alternativa?
* aunque en la imagen solo un objeto es devuelto, podrian ser muchos.

Comment: Por favor coloca una muestra de los datos de entrada y los datos de salida, que es como esperas obtener esa información; en forma de texto, las imágenes salvo que sean necesarias no se debe usar y en este caso el código es corto bien puedes reemplazarlo como te digo.

Comment: Puedes usar el método `map` de la clase Array para transformar cada objeto en un array de dos elementos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterando usando el método `.map()` sobre tu array de objetos, puedes convertir la estructura que recibes prácticamente a conveniencia.

En este caso, generando un nuevo `Array` con la estructura que quieres.

Te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
const originalArr =[
  {fecha: "Ene", total_mes: 20.00},
  {fecha: "Feb", total_mes: 24.00},
  {fecha: "Mar", total_mes: 10.00},
  {fecha: "Abr", total_mes: 15.00},
  {fecha: "May", total_mes: 66.66},
  {fecha: "Jun", total_mes: 12.00},
  {fecha: "Jul", total_mes: 25.00},
  {fecha: "Ago", total_mes: 15.00},
  {fecha: "Sep", total_mes: 2.00},
  {fecha: "Oct", total_mes: 5.00},
  {fecha: "Nov", total_mes: 1.00},
  {fecha: "Dic", total_mes: 125.00},
]

const myNewArr = originalArr.map(el => [el.fecha, el.total_mes]);

console.log(myNewArr);
```